# sorted array with Number shuffle

Tags: ruby

i am working on the problem of Number shuffle https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/problems/154-permutations#solution4802. exercises asks to:

> return a sorted array of all the unique numbers that can be formed
>   with 3 or 4 digits.

there is a solution (See the Solution) below the exercise, that looks like this:

```
def number_shuffle(number)
  no_of_combinations = number.to_s.size == 3 ? 6 : 24
  digits = number.to_s.split(//)
  combinations = []
  combinations << digits.shuffle.join.to_i while 
combinations.uniq.size!=no_of_combinations
  combinations.uniq.sort
end
```

I have a few questions, can anyone explain me:

1) in 'no_of_combinations' variable what does it mean '3 ? 6 : 24'? i think 3 is amount of digits in the number. question mark ( ? ) is symbol of 'if'- if number digits are 3, the amount of numbers will be 6 in the array of combinations. colon (punctuation) is symbol sign, but i do not know why 24, there are 23 symbols considering white space in the array of combinations.

2) what does it mean << symbol after combinations? i know that it is addition sign, but what does it do here? and also, what it means exclamation mark after 'size' in the following string?

Comment: For modern Ruby, that solution could improved a lot. Starting with clearer syntax, but also this line `combinations << digits.shuffle.join.to_i while 
combinations.uniq.size!=no_of_combinations` ? Oh my . . . it's a terrible way to do this, and almost code obfuscation. Try feeding that function e.g. `3345` :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) in 'no_of_combinations' variable what does it mean '3 ? 6 : 24'?

The expression needs to include the comparison to make sense . . .

```
number.to_s.size == 3 ? 6 : 24
```

This is the [ternary if](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Ternary+if). If the comparison before the `?` is true, it evaluates to the first value (`6` here), if it is false it evaluates to the second value (`24` here). It has nothing to do with literal `Symbol` values . . . in fact Ruby parser will always treat the colon as a value separator here, however you space it.

The syntax of this operator is originally from C, and you will find it copied to many other languages.

> 2) what does it mean << symbol after combinations? i know that it is addition sign, but what does it do here?

It is not an addition sign. This operator does different things depending on the class of the object (on the left). In this example, that is an `Array`, and `<<` pushes the object on the right onto the end of the array. It is almost identical to `push`

> and also, what it means exclamation mark after 'size' in the following string?

In this case it is part of `!=`, or "not equals" comparison operator. The original author could have made this clearer with a bit of whitespace.